# CSS: mix-blend-mode = color-dodge not working in Chrome but okay in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, svg, mix-blend-mode

I am trying to use an effect where the same shape (SVG in my case) at different locations is overlayed, and its colors should be "color dodged". The shape is coming in the primary colors red, green and blue. Where all shapes meet, the color is white, and in other places combinations occur. I've created a pen at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgKQqz to demonstrate. In short, the styles:

```
body { background-color: #222; }
.demo { mix-blend-mode: color-dodge; }
.center { position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; }
.pr { transform: translate(-30%, -50%); }
.pg { transform: translate(-80%, -50%); }
.pb { transform: translate(-50%, -30%); }
```

And the shapes:

```
<svg class="demo center pr" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="#ff0000" />
</svg>
<svg class="demo center pg" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="#00ff00" />
</svg>
<svg class="demo center pb" width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="#0000ff" />
</svg>
```

This works as I expect in Firefox (62), but no mixing seems to take place in Chrome (70). The issue is not with SVG, as even regular text in a `div` element behaves like described.

Am I doing something wrong, can this be achieved so it works in both browsers, or is this a Chrome bug?

Comment: If I'm changing those SVG with divs it works in Chrome. I know there is an [issue with Chrome 58+](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=711955&q=mix-blend-mode&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) where `mix-blend-mode` will not render on elements that are set on a transparent `<body>` There may be a similar issue with SVGs

Comment: Also it works if I draw he circles on the same SVG canvas

Comment: @enxaneta - thanks; I found the issue in Chrome 58+ but couldn't find a good way around - I tried `background-color: rgba(16,16,16,0.8);` and `background-image` but neither make Chrome blend the circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact using the SVGs as `background-image` is working:

```css
.demo {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
}

body {
  background-color: #222;
}
.center {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.pr {
  transform: translate(-30%, -50%);
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100'%3E%3Ccircle cx='50' cy='50' r='40' fill='%23ff0000' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
.pg {
  transform: translate(-80%, -50%);
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100'%3E%3Ccircle cx='50' cy='50' r='40' fill='%2300ff00' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
.pb {
  transform: translate(-50%, -30%);
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100'%3E%3Ccircle cx='50' cy='50' r='40' fill='%230000ff' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div class="demo center pr"></div>
<div class="demo center pg"></div>
<div class="demo center pb"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look into this. It still does not work for me (only see the three circle in primary colors); however on a different machine with Chrome 69 your snippet actually shows as I'd expect it. So I assume this is a weird problem potentially related to the graphics driver/support.